# Gnuplot: draw error bars of data points outside plotting range

Tags: gnuplot

If I set a specific yrange and plot in a pdf terminal with this plot command:

```
plot "data.dat" u 1:4:5:6 w yerrorbars pt 6 ps 0.5 t "R_t"
```

errorbars that belong to data points outside the yrange, but end inside the yrange are not shown.
How do I force gnuplot to draw those. I already tried "set clip one/two"

Comment: You can't, and it doesn't make sense if you don't know where the data point is which this part of an errorbar belongs to.

Comment: Thanks for the information. If it makes sense or not depends on the situation. I can't show all data points, because the interesting portion of the graph would become to small, but it would make sense to have visible error bars to indicate the existence of measurements outside the plotting range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround I found is to plot the data 3 times, once for the central point and once for each side of the error bar.
Use "-" as symbol for the errorbars and use their own "errorbars" to draw a line to the central point.

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiplot to achieve this.

Set your plot to have zero `margins`, so the axes are on the border of the canvas, and switch of all `tics` and `borders` for the first plot.

Switch on the axes, tics etc. again, and do an empty plot that you set at the correct position using `set size` and `set origin`. You'll have to do some math to calculate the exact position.

Comment: If I understand you correctly that would allow me to plot things which are inside the yrange equivalent to the page height (outside the plot borders). That is not what I want to achieve. I want errorbars within my yrange to be drawn, even if the datapoint is outside the yrange.

Comment: You could erase the part outside of the range by overprinting it with white rectangles (`set object rect`). But gnuplot never prints a point or it's errorbar if it is outside of the current range. Only the drawing of connecting lines (`with linespoint`) can be controlled with `set clip`.

Answer (score 0):

@MaVo159, you can reduce it to plotting only twice by using `with yerrorbars` and `with vectors` (check `help vectors`). You need to set the proper arrow style, check `help arrowstyle`.
However, this works only for gnuplot>=5.2.3, for earlier versions there seems to be a bug which plots the arrowhead at the wrong side for some of the vectors extending the graph.

You nevertheless have to plot once `with yerrorbars` in order to get the proper legend.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.2.3, May 2018)

```
### plot errorbars from points outside the range
reset

$Data <<EOD
 1   9     5.11   8.32
 2   8     6.20   9.22
 3   6     5.31   6.31
 4   5     4.41   5.51
 5   4     3.31   4.71
 6   2.9   2.81   3.71
 7   2     1.11   3.41
EOD

set yrange[3:7]
set offsets 1,1,0,0
set style arrow 1 heads size 0.05,90 lw 2 lc 1

set multiplot layout 2,1

    plot $Data u 1:2:3:4 w yerrorbars pt 6 ps 2 lw 2
    
    plot $Data u 1:2:3:4 w yerrorbars pt 6 ps 2 lw 2, \
            '' u 1:3:(0):($4-$3) w vec as 1 notitle

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could modify your data file: Because the central value of the data point is outside the plot range you could set it equal to the errorbar's end point that would be still visible in your plot.

**Example:**

```
plot range: set yrange[-2:2]

data point: 1, -3, -1, -4 (x, y, ylow, yhigh)

set data point to: 1, -1, -1, -4
```

Attention: Since you have to edit your data file you should

1. Make a copy of the original data file
2. Be very careful when editing the file
3. Keep in mind, that when changing the plot range such that the central 
   value of the data point becomes visible you have to use the original data point. Otherwise you will see the correct error bar but there will be no central value plotted. (this is equivalent to setting 'point type' to 0)